# https showing different website

Tags: ssl, https

I developed the website in Laravel http://labim.com.np/ it is working fine. But today I noticed the website with https ie https://labim.com.np/ is showing different content. I have only cpanel access. I have been trying to find out what is going on. Is this related to WHM? because I didn't find anything related to https there(cpanel). There is ssl folder in root but there also I didn't find anything

Thank you for your any help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Since you are limited with Cpanel access , I dont you will be able to do any thing with the issue.

Better to contact your hosting service provider as they have root access and they will be able to fix the issue.

Comment: thanks I will do that, just want to confirm that it is not in my hand

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have installed SSL for winjewellery.com on IP 198.15.115.235 and http://labim.com.np/ is also on the same ip so when you access website labim.com.np with https it will show the content of the website for which SSL certificate is installed (winjewellery.com). You can move website http://labim.com.np/ to another IP which should resolve your issue. 
The best option is to contact your hosting provider.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, and why would my hosting provider point the multiple website to same IP? Is this some kind of virus activities?

Comment: There is no issue in using same ip for multiple websites but normally dedicated ip should be used for ssl and they might have assigned dedicated ip to winjewellery.com and install ssl and by mistake assign same ip to your website.